# How to retrieve Json data type data in SQL using a where condition in LARAVEL version upto 5.3

Tags: laravel

I have stored some data in Json data type in SQL. how can I retrieve it?

```
  [
    {
       id:5,
       name: stack
    }

  ]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> json where clauses this sould work

```
 $orders = DB::table('orders')
            ->whereJsonContains('Product', [['user' => ['id' => 1]]])
            ->get();
```